# Reading the attribute value without specifying the node name in xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've an xsl:variable like this,

```
<xsl:variable name="flag" 
       select="(/node1/@attr = 1) or (/node2/@attr = 1)"/>
```

Is it possible to read the attribute value without specifying the node name? so i can elimniate the `or` condition. Basically I feed two types of xml to the xslt, `node1` and `node2` are the root node names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/@attr = 1 or /*/@attr = 2
```

**If you need to eliminate the `or` opertor, do**:

```
contains(' 1 2 ', concat(' ', /*/@attr, ' '))
```

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) this can further be abbreviated to**:

```
/*/@attr = (1, 2)
```

Comment: Got one question. Will this /*/@attr checks all the child nodes also for that attribute or only the root node?

Comment: @Mark, Only the *top* element -- as required in the question.